# Will Elasticsearch survive this much load or simply die?

Tags: web, elasticsearch, scaling

We have Elasticsearch Server with 1 cluster 3 Nodes, we are expecting that queries fired per second will be 800-1000, so we want to know if we get load like 1000 queries per second then will the elasticsearch server respond with delays or it will simply stop working ?

- Queries are all `query_string`, fuzzy (prefix & wildcard queries are not used).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few factors to consider assuming that your network has the necessary throughput:

What's the CPU speed and number of cores for each node?
Should have 2GHZ quad cores at the very least. Also the nodes should be dedicated to ELK, so they aren't busy with other tasks.

How much ram do your nodes have?
Probably want to be north of 10GB at least

Are your logs filtered and indexed?
Having your logs filtered will greatly reduce the work load generated by the queries. Additionally, filtered logs can make it so that you don't have to query as much with wild cards (which are very expensive).

Hope that helps point in a better direction :)

Comment: we have 3 nodes each of 4 GB of ram, will it suffice?

Comment: You'll want more than that. If you're standing up the cluster as a proof of concept that amount of ram will work. If you have the goal of using it in production you'll want to upgrade.

Comment: sir upgrade to how much ram? secondly we are going with topology like 3 master+data nodes and 1 client node or should there be 2 client nodes for handling traffic of 1000-2000 per second?

Comment: From the devs of ELK

"A machine with 64 GB of RAM is the ideal sweet spot, but 32 GB and 16 GB machines are also common. Less than 8 GB tends to be counterproductive (you end up needing many, many small machines), and greater than 64 GB has problems that we will discuss in Heap: Sizing and Swapping."

How large is each record? I've not had issues at that scale using common commodity desktops in a proof of concept sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

One immediate suggestion: if you are expecting sustained query rates of 800 - 1K/sec you do *not* want the nodes storing the data (which will be handling indexing of new records, merging and shard rebalancing) to also be having to deal with query scatter/gather operations.  Consider a client + data node topology where you keep your 3 nodes and add n client nodes (data and master set to false in their configs.)  The actual value for n will vary based on your actual performance; this will be something you'll want to determine via experimentation.

Other factors equal or unknown, abundant memory is a good resource to have.  Review the [Elastic team's guidance on hardware](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html) and be sure to link through to the discussion on heap.

Comment: there wont be indexing of new records sir, nodes are only for searching